# How to hide "all" sections in isotope

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope

I have problem with this isotope, I want to when you start website, show only TEXT 1, not all like right's now.  I don't know how to make this, can you help me?

```js
// ISOTOPE FILTER
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 if ( $('.iso-box-wrapper').length > 0 ) { 

     var $container  = $('.iso-box-wrapper'), 
      $imgs   = $('.iso-box img');



     $container.imagesLoaded(function () {

      $container.isotope({
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    itemSelector: '.iso-box'
      });

      $imgs.load(function(){
       $container.isotope('reLayout');
      })

     });
        

     //filter items on button click

     $('.filter-wrapper li a').click(function(){

         var $this = $(this), filterValue = $this.attr('data-filter');

   $container.isotope({ 
    filter: filterValue,
    animationOptions: { 
        duration: 750, 
        easing: 'linear', 
        queue: false, 
    }                
   });             

   // don't proceed if already selected 

   if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) { 
    return false; 
   }

   var filter_wrapper = $this.closest('.filter-wrapper');
   filter_wrapper.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $this.addClass('selected');

       return false;
     }); 

 }

});
```

There's my code html

```html
<!-- portfolio section -->
<div id="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>Regulations</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- ISO section -->
                <div class="iso-section">
                    <ul class="filter-wrapper clearfix">
                         <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg selected" data-filter=".regulation">Regulation</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg" data-filter=".regulation2">Regulation 2</a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" class="opc-main-bg" data-filter=".regulation3">Regulation 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="iso-box-section">
                        <div class="iso-box-wrapper col4-iso-box">

                             <div class="iso-box regulation">
                                 <h3>
                                     TEXT 1
                                 </h3>
                                 <br>

                            </div>
                            <div class="iso-box regulation2">
                                  <h3>
                                      this is TEXT 2
                                 </h3>  
                                <br>
                            </div>

                             <div class="iso-box regulation3">
                                  <h3>
                                     and there's TEXT 3
                                 </h3>  
                            </div>




                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the current situtation.
[image: What I have]

And this is the result I want to 
[image: What I want]

[There's my code JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t5hnyb4/)

This code does not work very well on this website, because it needs additional JavaScript to work as I want it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to *filter* the content whenever you load the page. So just do that by telling the first time when you initialize Isotope to filter the items based on a string.

One way to do this is to hardcode the filter directly into the first time you call Isotope, but I would recommend getting the first value of the filters available and use that. That would allow you to change your HTML without having to change your JavaScript if you would add or remove filters.

```
// ISOTOPE FILTER
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if ($('.iso-box-wrapper').length > 0) {

    var $container = $('.iso-box-wrapper'),
      $imgs = $('.iso-box img'),
      $filters = $('.filter-wrapper li a');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {

      // Get the value of the first filter.
      var initialFilter = $filters.first().attr('data-filter');

      $container.isotope({
        filter: initialFilter,
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        itemSelector: '.iso-box',
      });

      $imgs.load(function() {
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
      })

    });


    //filter items on button click
    $filters.click(function() {

      var $this = $(this),
        filterValue = $this.attr('data-filter');

      $container.isotope({
        filter: filterValue,
        animationOptions: {
          duration: 750,
          easing: 'linear',
          queue: false,
        }
      });

      // don't proceed if already selected 

      if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
        return false;
      }

      var filter_wrapper = $this.closest('.filter-wrapper');
      filter_wrapper.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
      $this.addClass('selected');

      return false;
    });

  }

});
```